# How can i find out, what listener to unregister?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The problem is the following:

I got a listener on a array of callback's. They look like this:

```
static listeners = [];
```

They're in a js-file that adds and removes items of a array.

```
static items = [];
static listeners = [];

static add(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
    this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback());
};

static remove(item) {
    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
    this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback());

};

static register(callback) {
    this.listeners.push(callback);
};
```

I want to let a component know when the array changes and to re-render by setting state.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        items: ShoppingCartStore.items
    };
}

componentWillMount(){
    ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    ShoppingCartStore.removeEventListener(?, ?);
}

refresh() {
    this.setState({items: ShoppingCartStore.items})
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            <table className="pure-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>No</td>
                        <td>Item</td>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => <ShoppingCartRow key={i} index={i} item={item}/>) }
                    <ShoppingCartSumRow />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Other components listen on this array of listeners as well.
How can i find out what listener should be unregister?
I have to unregister the listener because i want to return to the main page where items are selected by customer and react can't setState on a unmounted component.
Thanks for any input and i apologize for my bad english

Comment: Where is the `removeEventListener` code? Usually (with some frameworks/reducers/state-managers) the `register`/`subscribe` function returns a `deregister` function, eg with redux: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/Store.md#subscribelistener

Comment: I thought js got a standard function for doing so. But to answer your question there is no code for removeEventListener. I found this api [Link]: (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) also i'm not allow to use more frameworks as they're in the project at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the callback function that you pass to register:

```
var callbackReference;
componentWillMount(){
     callbackReference = this.refresh.bind(this);
     ShoppingCartStore.register(callbackReference);
}
```

And then, you can write the `removeEventListener` function like this:

```
static removeEventListener(reference){
    var index = this.listeners.indexOf(reference);
    if(index != -1){
        this.listeners.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

And here is how you'll call it:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    ShoppingCartStore.removeEventListener(callbackReference);
}
```